# IIB Java Compute Node vs ESQL Compute Node

Tags: java, performance, ibm-integration-bus

What the pros anc cons of using Java compute node instead of esql compute node in IIB 9.0 ?
Is Java really slower than esql ?
Is there any example when JCN will suits better than ECN ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This subject is really complex, and we had to face it a few month ago, so we listed the pros and the cons I remember :

### ESQL

#### Pros

- Really efficient **if well written**
- Auto-completion based on the schema referenced by your application

#### Cons

- Really small community, meaning restricted help and support (and thus, harder maintenance of the code due to a lack of knowledge)
- You constantly have to re-code everything (ex : to split a string based on a separator, you have to write the full code yourself, by getting index of the separator, then cutting the string based on this index, and looping on this until you have no separator left)
- No automatic testing of your code
- Limited portability (works on all the OS supported by IIB, but when migrating to another tool ...)

I won't list all the points for Java, but everything listed above is the opposite for Java.

In my case, principally due to the lack of Unit Tests, I stopped using ESQL for complex code. I still use it to override properties in the local environment, or any really small tasks, but I won't write anything longer than 50 lines of code in ESQL (I target 10 lines max)